# Continue code execution after an error and deal with them later in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, email, try-catch

I'm coding a simple php code for sending e-mails from a MySQL table with a mailing list;
I'm doing the best I can to prevent errors from happening, to validate fields and do everything I can to prevent errors from happening.

I'm going to use a foreach loop to send each e-mail with names and other relevant information, but I'm worried that for some reason, some e-mail or name might raise an error and stop my code halfway through the list, leaving me with no way of knowing where it stopped.

I want to know if there's a way to skip the problematic row and keep on sending the e-mails, and then show details about the rows it failed sending.

I thought that I could use Try/Catch but I couldn't find if I could continue the code after the exception, and couldn't find how to append error mesages to display at the end.

If this isn't a good way to deal with possible errors, what's the best way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`try/catch` will definitely work for this. Since you're specifically concerned with continuing execution after the exception, keep in mind that it matters what is included in the `try` block. For example:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 'string', 5, 6];

try {
    foreach ($array as $number) {
        if (is_string($number)) throw new Exception("Not a number", 1);            
        echo $number;
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

with this code you would see

> 123Not a number

because after the exception is handled, execution will continue after the catch block, not at the point the exception was thrown.

Whereas, with the try/catch inside the foreach loop

```
foreach ($array as $number) {
    try {
        if (is_string($number)) throw new Exception("Not a number", 1);            
        echo $number;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

the loop would continue after the exception and you would see

> 123Not a number56

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the try/catch solution? It is perfectly described here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

"Normal execution (when no exception is thrown within the try block) will continue after that last catch block defined in sequence."

So you could put your send-function into a try/catch block -> if an error occurs write the error in an array and print the array after the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use try cacth to ignore errors

```
try {
    // your code here
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // here do nothing
}
```

If you want deal wjth the errors later, you could add exceptions to array and deal with the errors on finally block.

```
try {
    // your code
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // add error to error array
} finally {
    // deal with error array
}
```

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.exceptions.php